# Random placement of items on canvas without overlap

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, game-development, callstack

I'm trying to randomly place a number of items (sprites) onto a canvas element without any overlap. I'm using a seeded random number so that I can get consistent placement. However I'm running into a few issues. Firstly I very quickly reach a maximum call stack size with my recursive logic to avoid any collisions (Anywhere from merely 15 entities), so I don't know if there's a way I can optimise this. Secondly, when it does run successfully, my entities all have a tendency to be along the top and left side of my canvas, hence why there's probably a large amount of collisions.

Can anyone see any issues with this? I've tried just using Math.random() instead of `myrng()` to see if that is the issue but I get the same result.

```
//80 is the width of a single sprite
const getLocation = () => {
    let x = Math.floor(myrng() * (canvas.width - 80));
    let y = Math.floor(myrng() * (canvas.height - 80));

    x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
    y = y < 0 ? 0 : y;

    const overlap = entities.some((entity) => {
      return (x - entity.position.x < 80 || y - entity.position.y < 80);
    });

    if (!overlap) {
      return [x, y];
    } else {
      return getLocation();
    }
  };
```

`myrng()` is the seeded random number generator from the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/seedrandom

I call this before I begin calling my `update` method.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      const [x, y] = getLocation();
      entities.push({ position: { x, y } });
    }
```

Comment: The call stack issue could be avoided by _not_ doing this recursively. Do it in a loop instead, until there is no collision. (That also makes it easy to implement a limit, so that you can break the process off if it still hasn't found a free position after x attempts.)

Comment: @CBroe that's the issue with this sort of code, it is non-deterministic. If you have enough items placed on the canvas, finding a new spot can take various times, sometimes even minutes. I would rather think of the canvas as an array of possible positions and use the random to consume elements from that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overlap` calculation appears to be incorrect. Try

```js
const overlap = entities.some((entity) => {
      return Math.abs(x - entity.position.x) < 80 
          && Math.abs(y - entity.position.y) < 80);
    });
```

The reasoning being that if either of the `x` or `y` values of two entities are *not* within 80px of each other they do *not* overlap.

Running out of stack space could be a consequence of recursively calling `getLocation` when there is no canvas space of 80 x 80 px unoccupied on the canvas. More design is needed but checking that some existing entity differs from every other entity by not less than 80px in both the x and y direction is probably necessary. If there is no solution remaining, recursions should pop an entity of the entiies array before the recursive call.

Comment: Thinks, I should have noticed that, it's also fixed the issue with pinning the items to the left and top